# How to regulate voltage at receiver in Visual light communication

Tags: led, communication, photodiode

Consider an LED, transmitting data which is stationary and a moving receiver placed on a car. There is a photodiode which receives the data. The car moves at a speed, when the car approaches the led the current increases and then it passes the LED the current slowly decreases.

Here's my doubt.
Should I convert the current from photodiode to voltage and regulate the voltage. 
Or should I limit the current  and then change it into voltage. So basically what I'm asking is how to make the system adaptive?

Comment: I recommend you study circuits used for traffic light controls from emergency vehicles. (I did.) These deal with precisely your situation (except who is transmitting and who is receiving is different and the size factors of the xmitter and receivers are probably different.) They deal with ambient solar (and other) light sources, different distances (up to a point), and so on. I'd list the specific techniques they apply, but I don't have time to bother with an answer today. So this is just a recommendation you go find circuits that do this, already.

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is called *automatic gain control* (AGC).

I don't know what an AGC circuit best for amplifying a photodiode looks like, but I'm sure you can find information and examples better now that you know what it's called.

Answer (score 2):

> So basically what I'm asking is how to make the system adaptive

The light power received in the signal is inversely proportional to distance so if the light power received is (say) 100 uW at 1 metre distance then at 10 metres this will be 1 uW and at 100 metres this will be 10 nW.

This is the backdrop - your dynamic range is going to be in the order of 10,000:1 and YOU WILL need an AGC (automatic gain control) circuit just as a radio receiver uses AGC to control the amplitudes of the received signals so they can be properly demodulated.

You will also need to ensure that the data you transmit is modulated away from DC i.e. you use something like Manchester encoding. This means that the receive signal can be high-pass filtered to remove the effects of sunlight and heat i.e. those big nasty signals that are close to DC need to be removed.

So, given the dynamic range of the signal, you would likely choose to modulate the transmit data onto a carrier (exactly like radio and maybe by using manchester encoding) and then use a band-pass filter in the receive circuit. This will minimize any general noise that may be present that could cause a "too-simple" receiver to improperly and ineffectively operate i.e. you are trying to make a system with low bit error rates.

You might even decide that a good checksum is needed and that you need to transmit data in frames/packets. All this is exactly what radio systems do and they do it to improve the bit-error-rate.

So, the tricks to make it work effectively and adaptively are: -

- Modulate the transmitted data
- Frame the transmitted data
- Apply good checksums to the frames

then for the receiver: -

- Use a low noise photodiode amplifier like a TIA using a good op-amp
- High pass filter the signal output
- Use an amplitude detector to determine the signal size
- Use an AGC to limit the spread of signal size based on the amplitude detector
- Band-pass filter the signal
- Use a data slicer
- Feed into an MCU to demodulate and decode the frame and handle the data.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a transimpedance amplifier to convert the current to a voltage. This voltage is then easy to regulate, analyse or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

What you are talking about is VLC (*Visible Light Communication*) and as far as I know it is most commonly done with TIA (*Transimpedance Amplifier*). So I would suggest a TIA with AGC (*Automatic Gain Control*) like @KevinReid said.